# Viewing the statement in EXECUTE with USING

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

Let's say with the below function, I need to debug what is executed inside the `EXECUTE` statement. (a long, dynamic statement with dynamic variables provided in `USING` in reality)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn() RETURNS integer LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE $x$
        SELECT $1, $2, $3
    $x$ USING 1, '2020-01-01'::date, NULL::date;
    
    RETURN 0;
END;
$$;
```

It seems that in such a case the best you can do is to get back the string `SELECT $1, $2, $3`. Is there any way to print/raise `SELECT 1, '2020-01-01'::date, NULL::date`?
(I would imagine something like `format('%1$s', 'xyz')`?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more sophisticated than one might expect. PL/pgSQL `EXECUTE` strips comments and parses the query string, identifying tokens. Only actual `$`-parameters are then replaced with values from the `USING` clause, before planning the query. Not `$n` contained in comments, strings or identifiers (like `-- $1 is required`, `'My text says $2'` or `"costs$3"`). We would have to duplicate much of the parser's functionality to be as accurate.

But I have been wishing for the same functionality in the past. So here goes:

Plain `replace()` will be fooled by any occurrence of `$n` that is not an actual parameter. Here is a poor-man's implementation that should do a better job. And it includes type data types. (But it's still far from perfect!)

First a little helper function: Postgres provides a [couple of functions to format strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) as identifier, literal etc:

```
quote_ident()
quote_literal()
quote_nullable()
```

We need this one:

> `quote_nullable` ( `anyelement` ) → `text`
>
> Converts the given value to text and then quotes it as a literal; or,
> if the argument is null, returns `NULL`. Embedded single-quotes and
> backslashes are properly doubled.

But with an appended cast to the original data type. So I call it **`quote_nullable_typed()`**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quote_nullable_typed(anyelement)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT quote_nullable($1) || '::' || pg_typeof($1);
$func$;
```

`format()` has format specifiers inlining the functionality of the mentioned `quote_*()` functions: `%I`, `%L`. Not for our custom function, obviously. So apply it explicitly and pass the result with `%s`. Nested in another helper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_sql_string_with_params(_sql text, VARIADIC x text[])
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE AS
$func$
SELECT format(regexp_replace(replace(_sql, '%', '%%')
                           , '(?<=[^[:alnum:]_''"])\$(\d+)(?=[^[:alnum:]_''"])'
                           , '%\1$s'
                           , 'g'
                            )
            , x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10])  -- allow more?
$func$;
```

The `VARIADIC` parameter accepts a variable number of parameters. The function iterates through the first 10 (arbitrarily). If you need more, expand the list.

Core functionality is:

```
regexp_replace(replace(_sql, '%', '%%'), '(?<=[^[:alnum:]_''"])\$(\d+)(?=[^[:alnum:]_''"])', '%\1$s', 'g')
```

Double up any `%` to prepare for `format()`. See:

- [What does %% in PL/pgSQL mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22870279/939860)

The regexp pattern `(?<=[^[:alnum:]_''"])\$(\d+)(?=[^[:alnum:]_''"])` explained:

`(?<=)` ...  [positive lookbehind](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE)
`[^[:alnum:]_''"]` ... character class excluding word characters and `_'"`
`\$` ... literal `$`
`(\d+)` ... one or more digits in capturing parentheses (noted for replacement)
`(?=)` ...  [positive lookahead](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINTS-TABLE)

So it only replaces `$n` when not between word characters or next to quotes. **Far from perfect.** But should cover typical cases.

Ideally, we would strip comments first. Who ever feels in the mood to improve it further ...

Applied to your original example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text := $q$SELECT $1, $2, $3, 'false $1', format('demo: %I', 'xX')$q$;  -- sql string, extended with potential hazards
   _v1  int  := 1;
   _v2  date := '2020-01-01';
   _v3  date;  -- defaults to NULL
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE E'Query string with $-parameters:\n%', _sql;

   RAISE NOTICE E'Query string with typed values:\n%'
              , f_sql_string_with_params(_sql
                                       , quote_nullable_typed(_v1)
                                       , quote_nullable_typed(_v2)
                                       , quote_nullable_typed(_v3)
                                        );
   
   EXECUTE _sql
   USING _v1, _v2, _v3;
END
$func$;
```

The second `NOTICE` will report:

```
SELECT '1'::integer, '2020-01-01'::date, NULL::date;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=eb0b33003e96f8dad451a4a1accdf774)* - with extended test case

Comment: Works like a charm! Really appreciate the explanations too.

Answer (score 1):

`RAISE NOTICE` should do the trick:

```
RAISE NOTICE '$1 = "%", $2 = "%", $3 = "%"', 1, '2020-01-01'::date, NULL::date;
```

To interpolate the values in the query, you can use

```
replace(
   replace(
      replace('SELECT $1, $2, $3', '$1', '1'),
      '$2', '''2020-01-01''::date'
   ),
   '$3', 'NULL::date'
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I see it can print out the arguments. I wonder if there is any way to substitute the $1, $2 etc inside the `EXECUTE` statement and print it out though?

Comment: You could use `replace` as in my updated answer. If you want to do that in a generic fashion, you'll have to loop through the parameters, and you won't be able to retain the type information, so the resulting query might not be a runnable SQL statement.